# How to write my own split function without using .split and .strip function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to write my own split function? I just think I should remove spaces, `'\t'` and `'\n'`. But because of the shortage of knowledge, I have no idea of doing this question

Here is the original question:

> Write a function split(string) that returns a list of words in the
>   given string. Words may be separated by one or more spaces `' '` , tabs
>   `'\t'` or newline characters `'\n'` .
>
> And there are examples:
>
> ```
> words = split('duff_beer 4.00') # ['duff_beer', '4.00']
> words = split('a b c\n') # ['a', 'b', 'c']
> words = split('\tx y \n z ') # ['x', 'y', 'z']
> ```
>
> Restrictions: Don't use the `str.split` method! Don't use the `str.strip` method

Comment: Did you try to solve this ?

Comment: Can you use `re.split()` ?

Comment: use `rsplit()` to avoid the arbitrary restrictions ;)

Comment: @VineethSai I just think I could split every letter by list() function and remove spaces '\t' and '\n'. But in this case, I cannot combine them into the original word.

Comment: @Austin I think no... The question is more likely to request me not to use split() these kind of functions.

Comment: What you need are [Regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

Comment: Which version of python?

Comment: @pygo python 3 I think

Comment: @AnYan,  though i have added mu answer below but you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877531/splitting-strings-in-python-without-split) .. all are answers there..

Answer (score 7):

Some of the comments on your question provide really interesting ideas to solve the problem with the given restrictions.

But assuming you should not use any python builtin split function, here is another solution:

```
def split(string, delimiters=' \t\n'):
    result = []
    word = ''
    for c in string:
        if c not in delimiters:
            word += c
        elif word:
            result.append(word)
            word = ''

    if word:
        result.append(word)

    return result
```

Example output:

```
>>> split('duff_beer 4.00')
['duff_beer', '4.00']
>>> split('a b c\n')
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> split('\tx y \n z ')
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: if fails because "axxaxa".split("xx") != split("axxaxa", "xx")

Answer (score 4):

I think using regular expressions is your best option as well.

I would try something like this:

```
import re
def split(string):
    return re.findall('\S+',string)
```

This should return a list of all none whitespace characters in your string.

Example output:

```
>>> split('duff_beer 4.00')
['duff_beer', '4.00']
>>> split('a b c\n')
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> split('\tx y \n z ')
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to iterate over every char until you find a seperator, built a string from that chars and append it to the outputlist like this:

```
def split(input_str):
    out_list = []
    word = ""
    for c in input_str:
        if c not in ("\t\n "):
            word += c
        else:
            out_list.append(word)
            word = ""
    out_list.append(word)
    return out_list

a = "please\nsplit\tme now"
print(split(a))

# will print: ['please', 'split', 'me', 'now']
```

Another thing you could do is by using regex:

```
import re

def split(input_str):
    out_list = []
    for m in re.finditer('\S+', input_str):
        out_list.append(m.group(0))

    return out_list

a = "please\nsplit\tme now"
print(split(a))

# will print: ['please', 'split', 'me', 'now']
```

The regex `\S+` is looking for any sequence of non whitespace characters and the function `re.finditer` returns an iterator with MatchObject instances over all non-overlapping matches for the regex pattern.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you can do with assigning a list, This is tested on python3.6

Below is Just an example..

```
values = 'This is a sentence'
split_values = []
tmp  = ''
for words in values:
    if words == ' ':
        split_values.append(tmp)
        tmp = ''
    else:
        tmp += words
if tmp:
    split_values.append(tmp)
print(split_values)
```

**Desired output:**

```
$ ./splt.py
['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function that sticks to the basics, as your professor apparently prefers:

```
def split(s):
    output = []
    delimiters = {' ', '\t', '\n'}
    delimiter_found = False
    for c in s:
        if c in delimiters:
            delimiter_found = True
        elif output:
            if delimiter_found:
                output.append('')
                delimiter_found = False
            output[-1] += c
        else:
            output.append(c)
    return output
```

so that:

```
print(split('duff_beer 4.00'))
print(split('a b c\n'))
print(split('\tx y \n z '))
```

would output:

```
['duff_beer', '4.00']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find my solution, it is not the best one, but it works:

```
def convert_list_to_string(b):
    localstring=""
    for i in b:
        localstring+=i
    return localstring

def convert_string_to_list(b):
    locallist=[]
    for i in b:
        locallist.append(i)
    return locallist

def mysplit(inputString, separator):
    listFromInputString=convert_string_to_list(inputString)
    part=[]
    result=[]
    j=0
    for i in range(0, len(listFromInputString)):
        if listFromInputString[i]==separator:
            part=listFromInputString[j:i]
            j=i+1
            result.append(convert_to_string(part))
        else:
            pass
    if j != 0:
        result.append(convert_to_string(listFromInputString[j:]))
    if len(result)==0:
        result.append(inputString)
    return result
```

Test:

```
mysplit("deesdfedefddfssd", 'd')
```

Result: ['', 'ees', 'fe', 'ef', '', 'fss', '']

Answer (score 0):

Some of your solutions are very good, but it seems to me that there are more alternative options than using the function:

```
values = 'This is a sentence'
split_values = []
tmp = ''
for words in values:
    if words == ' ':
        split_values.append(tmp)
    tmp = ''
else:
    tmp += words
if tmp:
    split_values.append(tmp)
    print(split_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

a is string and s is pattern here.

```
a="Tapas Pall Tapas TPal TapP al Pala"
s="Tapas"
def fun(a,s):
  st=""
  l=len(s)
  li=[]
  lii=[]
  for i in range(0,len(a)):
      if a[i:i+l]!=s:
        st=st+a[i]
    elif i+l>len(a):
        st=st+a[i]
    else:
        li.append(st)
        i=i+l
        st=""
  li.append(st)
  lii.append(li[0])
  for i in li[1:]:
      lii.append(i[l-1:])
  return lii
print(fun(a,s))
print(a.split(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

> This handles for whitespaces in strings and returns empty lists if present

```
def mysplit(strng):
    #
    # put your code here
    #
    result = []
    words = ''
    
    for char in strng:
        if char != ' ':
            words += char
        else:
            if words:
                result.append(words)
            words = ''
            
            
    result.append(words)
    
    for item in result:
        if item == '':
            result.remove(item)
    
    return result

print(mysplit("To be or not to be, that is the question"))
print(mysplit("To be or not to be,that is the question"))
print(mysplit("   "))
print(mysplit(" abc "))
print(mysplit(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mysplit(strng):
my_string = ''
liste = []
for x in range(len(strng)):
    my_string += "".join(strng[x])
    if strng[x] == ' ' or x+1 == len(strng):
        liste.append(my_string.strip())
        my_string = ''
        liste = [elem for elem in liste if elem!='']
return liste
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to provide **algorithm** before **coding**:
This is the procedure for splitting words on delimiters without using any python built in method or function:

0. Initialize an **empty list**  [] called **result** which will be used to save the resulting list of words, and an **empty** string called  **word = ""** which will be used to concatenate each block of string.
1. Keep adding string characters as long as the delimiter is not reached
2. When you **reach** the **delimiter**, and **len(word) = 0**, Don't do whatever is below. Just go to the next iteration. This will help detecting and removing **leading spaces**.
3. When you **reach** the **delimiter**, and **len(word) != 0**, Append word to result, reinitialize word and jump to the next iteration without doing whatever is below
4. Return result

```
def my_split(s, delimiter = [" ","\t"]): 
  result,word = [], "" # Step 0
   
  N = len(s)
  for i in range(N) : #

    if N == 0:#  Case of empty string
      return result

    else: # Non empty string        
      
      if s[i] in delimiter and len(word) == 0: # Step 2     
        continue # Step 2: Skip, jump to the next iteration
      if s[i] in delimiter and len(word) != 0: # Step 3        
        result.append(word) # Step 3
        word = "" # Step 3
        continue # Step 3: Skip, jump to the next iteration          
      
      word = word + s[i] # Step 1.
  
     
  return result

print(my_split("        how are    you?  please split me now!       "))
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are good, there is a similar solution with an extra empty list.

```
def my_split(s):
    l1 = []
    l2 = []
    word = ''
    spaces = ['', '\t', ' ']
    for letters in s:
        if letters != ' ':
            word += letters
        else:
            l1.append(word)
            word = ''
    if word:
        l1.append(word)

    for words in l1:
        if words not in spaces:
            l2.append(words)

    return l2


my_string = '       The old fox jumps into the deep river'
y = my_split(my_string)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

split first removes the beginning and ending character and then it converts your string into list based on the character you have input in the function. the default character is " " so i have done this using " ".

```
def my_split(string):
    string=string.strip(" ")
    ans=[]
    word=""
    for character in string:
        if character!=" ":
            word+=character
        else:
            ans.append(word)
            word=""
    ans.append(word)
    return ans
print(my_split(input("Enter string")))
```