# a problem with replace function in python (replaces identical string)

Tags: python, replace

hello i have a small function that verifies if a an IPV4 addresses is valid or not . what it essentially does is check if the numbers between the dots are between  0 and 255 :
example :
IPV4 addressee : 120.62.102.52
this ip is valid cause all the numbers (120/62/102/52) are between 0 and 255
another example :
IPV4 addressee : 120.940.102.52
this ip is not valid cause the number (940) is not between 0 and 255
my code works what it does in a for loop of 4 (cause there is 4 numbers) it checks if the int of the first character until the first "." is between 0 and 255 if it is it deletes that section of the string using the replace method and carry on checking the numbers using the same method if the condition is not met it breaks from the loop and returns not valid  .
i hope the code will make things more clear

```
def ValidIPv4(ch):
aux = ch
breaking = False
for i in range(4):
    if breaking == False  :
                    if i != 3 :
                        if 0<=int(aux[0:aux.index(".")])<=255   :
                            aux=aux.replace(aux[0:aux.index(".")+1],"")
                        else:  
                            breaking = True
                    else:
                        if not 0<=int(aux)<=255   :
                            breaking = True   
if breaking == False:
    print("IPV4 is valid")
else:
    print("IPV4 non valid")
```

print(ValidIPv4("120.62.102.52"))

the code works fine in 90% of cases but the problem is when the ip addressee has 2 identical numbers like 120.62.120.52 for example (120 is repeated twice )
it returns this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\Users\amine\Desktop\pyyyy\2013\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(ValidIPv4("120.62.120.52"))
  File "c:\Users\amine\Desktop\pyyyy\2013\test.py", line 7, in ValidIPv4
    if 0<=int(aux[0:aux.index(".")])<=255   :
ValueError: substring not found
```

it does because it replace the 120 and the second 120 at the same time for some reason .
why does it doe that ? and what's the solution ??

Comment: Is this for educational purpose ? Otherwise i suggest you take a look at the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module in the stdlib.

Comment: ye its for an exam

Comment: could you try the code and explain why ??

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier, if we split the given ip address into parts like `192.168.50.1.split('.')` and the check if each one is between `0-255` ? Like `parts = [int(x) for x in  ip.split('.')]; return all(0 <= part <= 255 for part in parts)`

Comment: i cant use those functions cause its not available in our algorithm functions list (this an algorithm translated to py )

Comment: That is not happening "for some reason", it's just how `replace` works: it replaces *every* occurrence of the pattern in the string. If you'd like to change your code as little as possible, you can pass a third argument to `replace(x, y, 1)` that tells it to replace only one match. But take a look at Sujay's answer below, you might like to rethink how you approach the problem.

Comment: i have added ,1 to the argument but the same problem occurs

Comment: worked now thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually just need to split the string and check if all numbers are between 0 and 255:

```
def check_ip(ip_add):
    return "Valid IP Address" if all(0<=int(i)<=255 for i in ip_add.split('.')) else "Invalid IP Address"
print(check_ip("120.620.102.52"))
```

To return a list, you can do the following:

```
return '.'.join(i for i in ip_add.split('.') if 0<=int(i)<=255)
```

If you don't want to use `.split()` you can try this:

```
def check_ip(ip_add):
    
    sentence = ip_add
    split_value = []
    tmp = ''
    for c in sentence:
        if c == '.':
            split_value.append(tmp)
            tmp = ''
        else:
            tmp += c
    if tmp:
        split_value.append(tmp)

    return '.'.join(i for i in split_value if 0<=int(i)<=255)
print(check_ip("120.40.102.52"))
```

The code for splitting the string was derived here:

[Splitting strings in Python without split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877531/splitting-strings-in-python-without-split)

Comment: i cant use the split function and i want to understand why replace function does this can you check pls ?

Comment: @emilyjhonson Are you allowed to implement your own split function?

Comment: @Sujay In my opinion your function's signature should be something like `is_address_valid(str) -> bool` and the appropriate text should be created by the program calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

It replaces both numbers because you are telling the program to do so, when you write this

`aux = aux.replace(aux[0:aux.index(".")+1], "")`

Instead, you can mask the part that you want to remove by using the appropriate slicing indexes:

`aux = aux[aux.index(".")+1:]`

Now of course using `split` would be the most logical thing to do but you said somewhere else that it's not allowed in your exercise.

If you are forced to use `replace` and slicing is not allowed, use the `count` keyword to replace only the first match:

`aux = aux.replace(aux.index(".")+1, "", count=1)`