# Spliting the list without Split() function in python

Tags: python

I am splitting the words without the split() function but I am getting every character in the list of the string.

```
i=0
def n_split(i_str):
    new_list= []
    for i in range(len(i_str)):
        if i_str[i]!=' ':
            new_list += i_str[i]
            i+=1
    return new_list


inp_str=input("Enter the string:")
print("List:")
print(n_split(inp_str))
```

Comment: *"I am splitting the words without the split() function"* Why?

Comment: The reason you're getting every character of the string in the list is because the for loop over the string will iterate over all the characters of the string. If you want to split on <space>, then collect all the characters up to space into a string, and then add the string into the list.

Comment: You need one list (or string variable) to collect characters of a word and a list to collect the completed words.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting strings in Python without split()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32877531/6045800)

Comment: You also didn't specify what is wrong with your code and what does your input look like. Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 3):

```
i=0
def n_split(i_str):
    new_list= []
    str=''
    for i in range(len(i_str)):
        if i_str[i]!=' ':
            str+=i_str[i]
        else:
            new_list.append(str)
            str=''
    new_list.append(str)
    return new_list


inp_str=input("Enter the string:")
print("List:")
print(n_split(inp_str))
```

Try using this code.
here append function is used to add characters in string to list.
No need of i+=1

Comment: This just puts every letter as a list element. Not sure that's what is expected

Answer (score 2):

Detect words first then append them to the list:

```
def n_split(i_str):
    new_list= []
    word=''
    for i in range(len(i_str)):
        if i_str[i]!=' ':
            word += i_str[i]
        else:
            new_list.append(word)
            word =''
    new_list.append(word) #for the last word
    return new_list

inp_str=input("Enter the string:")
print("List:")
print(n_split(inp_str))
```

Comment: The last word is not getting appended

Comment: I edited the code to include the last word

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are adding every ***character*** to your array that is `not equal` to a space. But what you ***want*** is to have an array full of words, not just characters. So, the fix might look something like this.

```py
def n_split(i_str):
    new_list= [] ; new_word = ""
    for i in range(0, len(i_str)):
        if i_str[i]!=' ': # Add char to current word if not space
            new_word += i_str[i]
            #i+=1
        else: # Else, add current word to array
            new_list.append(new_word)
            new_word = ""
    # collect the last word as well;
    # we need this line because the last character probably is not a space
    if new_word !="": 
        new_list.append(new_word)
    return new_list
```

I also removed the `i=0` and `i+=1`, and just added the starting point 0 to the for-loop because they are redundant -- the `for i in range` can take care of that for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
def n_split(i_str):
    split_list= []
    new_list= ''
    for i in range(len(i_str)):
        if i_str[i]!=' ':
            new_list += i_str[i]
        else:
            split_list.append(new_list)
            new_list = ''
    split_list.append(new_list) #appending last word
    return split_list
 
inp_str=input("Enter the string:")
print("List:")
print(n_split(inp_str))
```

As you are using the range function i will iterate from 0 to len(i_str). So, no need to initialize i and increment it.

Collect all characters until you find a space and add that string to a new list.